# Why the mentioned assembly block is skipped?

Tags: solidity, evm

A very simple function:

```
function test(uint256 i) public {
   uint256 j;
   uint256 k = 4;
   assembly {
       pop(4)
   }
   uint256 l = 5;
}
```

- I checked debugging it in Remix but the assembly block is ignored, why ?
- Why EVM pushes 0 onto stack before pushing 'k' ?